MATLAB - Coloring the area bounded by two curves in polar coordinate system
I'm new to Matlab and I'm trying to write a code that draws these two curves in polar coordinate system and colors the area bounded by them.
r1 = 3 * sin(theta)
r2 = 1 + sin(theta)
I've tried several preliminary methods, but to no avail.
I'm using Matlab R2022b

You might have to use pol2cart to convert from polar to cartesian coordinates, which opens up more of the standard plotting functions like patch
Example input:
theta = linspace(0,pi,2000);
r1 = 3 * sin(theta);
r2 = 1 + sin(theta);

Plotting code:
[x1,y1] = pol2cart( theta, r1 );
[x2,y2] = pol2cart( theta, r2 );
figure; hold on;
patch([x1 fliplr(x2)], [y1 fliplr(y2)], [0.7,0.9,0.9], 'displayname', 'fill', 'linestyle', 'none')
plot( x1, y1, 'r', 'linewidth', 2, 'displayname', 'r1' );
plot( x2, y2, 'b', 'linewidth', 2, 'displayname', 'r2' );
legend( 'show' );

Note if you go past pi for theta then the definition of which region is between the lines gets a little ambiguous, but from here you have all the coordinates to define the fill boundary and the ability to calculate them differently.


this doesn't work because theta must be between 0 and 2*pi and when you modify the first line to achieve that, it colors the whole area inside of r2 instead of the area between r1 and r2.
is there a way to use the fill function to accomplish this?

@confusedcoder please [edit] your question to include details like the required range, and ideally a sketch of the area you expect to be shaded - it's ambiguous which bit you would expect to be shaded over [0,2pi] (since the red circle repeats itself). Can you just treat [pi,2*pi] as independent from [0,pi] and repeat the above code on the 2nd half?

I found the answer. thanks for your effort my friend

I found the answer. this code worked for me
clc
clear
close all

f1 = @(t) 3*sin(t);
f2 = @(t) 1 + sin(t);

syms t
T = solve(f2(t) - f1(t));

theta = linspace(T(1), T(2), 300);

r1 = f1(theta);
r2 = f2(theta);

x1 = r1 .* cos(theta);
y1 = r1 .* sin(theta);

x2 = r2 .* cos(theta);
y2 = r2 .* sin(theta);

fill([x1, fliplr(x2)], [y1, fliplr(y2)], 'g', 'FaceAlpha', 0.7);

hold on

t = linspace(0,2*pi, 300);
plot(f1(t).*cos(t),f1(t).*sin(t))
plot(f2(t).*cos(t),f2(t).*sin(t))

axis equal

